# copy and rename files starting at a specific integer value in python

Tags: python-3.x, copy, file-rename

My codes work but for a few pain points that perhaps you can help me understand.  I want to copy files from one directory to another and rename them at the same time.  for example:

```
c:\path\
octo.jpeg
novem.jpeg
decem.jpeg
```

to:

```
c:\newpath\
001.jpeg
002.jpeg
003.jpeg
```

The codes I wrote from a cursory google search are as follows but I'm not sure why I need the 'r' in the path variables.  The 'files = os.listdir(srcPath)' line I'm sure I don't need.  This will move the files and renames them using the 'count' variable in the for loop but I want to name each file starting at a specific number, say 65.  Should I use the shutil library and copy2 method to first copy the files and then rename or is there an easier way?

```
import os
from os import path

srcPath = r'C:\Users\Talyn\Desktop\New folder\Keep\New folder'
destPath = r'C:\Users\Talyn\Desktop\New folder\Keep\hold'
#files = os.listdir(srcPath)

def main():

    for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(srcPath)):

        dst = '{:03d}'.format(count) + ".jpeg"
        
        os.rename(os.path.join(srcPath, filename), os.path.join(destPath, dst))


if __name__=="__main__":
    
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

From the official Python [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters.

The `r` is telling python interpreter to treat the backslashes(`\`) in the path string as literal characters and not as escaping characters.

For naming the files from a specific number:

```py
dst = '{:03d}'.format(count + your_number) + ".jpeg"
```

---

Using `copyfile` from `shutil`

```py
copyfile(srcPath + filename, destPath + dst)
```